# Nodejs process freezes

Tags: javascript, node.js, process, freeze

I have a huge script (3 modules x 2000 lines each one) which runs about 3000 times per day. Few times a week it freezes. Nodejs process is still running on Linux server, but nothing happens, it just stops working without any understandable reason. I've tried to write logs everywhere it was possible with `try ... catch`, but there is still no errors or warnings. It hangs in different places, different loops. There are also no errors in server logs.
Are there any other ways to debug such problem?

Answer (score 0):

in your main file( the file which your start app) put these codes :

```
// to log all bugs that occured in synchronus code but not handlled anywhere (add below code on top of your main file) 
  process.on('uncaughtException', err => {
  console.log('uncaughtException!! shutting down...');
  console.log(err.name, err.message);
  process.exit(1);
});
```

```
// to log all unhandledRejection in you APP (Async Code)
  process.on('unhandledRejection', (err) => {
  console.error(`Error Name : ${err.name}\nError Message : ${err.message}`);
  console.error(`unhandledRejection! Shutting Down...`);
    process.exit(1); // 0 for success & 1 for uncaught exeptions
});
```

By these lines of codes, when any problem happen in your app you can observe errors wich you haven't handle on your code.

Comment: Thank you, but unfortunately this solution didn't help me